# Is it possible to use column name as variable in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In Kusto, can I do this?

```
let my_var = "prefix";
let my_custom_col = strcat(my_var, "_something");
my_tab | extend my_custom_col = "5"
```

I tried it but it creates a column with name, `my_custom_col`  not with the name `prefix_something`.

Is it possible to use a variable as a column name in Kusto?

Answer (score 1):

you can use columnifexist function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/columnifexists

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in Kusto.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very tidy, but you can do with with `bag_unpack`.

```
let _column_name = 'Column name';
print 'test'
| project _bag = bag_pack(_column_name, State)
| evaluate bag_unpack(_bag)
```

bag_unpack docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin